# Paper.js Ipad Ios7 Runtime error?

Tags: ipad, runtime-error, ios7, paperjs

When I play around with this compass

http://onlyabutton.com/interactive/compass2.html

on the iPad, it crashes.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a fix for a very obscure text related bug that was happening on iOS 7:

https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/306

Please check if this resolves your issue.